# Need suggestion for creating the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a requirement, where if a user clicks a row of the table or a button, a view should be displayed below the table or button.

Also, the top view of the table should auto shrink, so that the user can see the details view without the need to scroll.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Regards
Akshat

Answer (score 0):

If you want a div to permanently appear under your clickable button/row then you will need to first make that div hidden using:

```
displaye:none;
```

Then with JQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   $('#div_content').toggle();
});
```

Alternative you could set the display to none then make it so when you hold down your click on the element the display becomes visible:

```
button:active + #div {
  display:visible;
}

#div {
  display:none;
}
```

Just place the hidden div below the element you want it to appear under.